# How to get the output of "wmic process call create"

Tags: windows, cmd

I'm trying to get the output of `wmic process call create` so I can get the `ProcessId` of the newly created process. If I just run:

```
wmic process call create "notepad.exe a.txt","d:\"
```

It works just fine (it opens the file `a.txt` under folder `d:\` with `notepad`). Now, if I try:

```
for /f "usebackq delims==; tokens=1,2" %i in (`wmic process call create "notepad.exe a.txt","d:\"^|findstr ProcessId`) do @echo pid = %j
```

It doesn't, and shows me the error:

> Formato incorrecto.
>   Sugerencia: <lista_parámetros> = <parámetro> [, <lista_parámetros>].

I don't really know what's going on here, can anyone explain this to me or if this is possible at all?

**NOTE:** Other commands work fine. For instance, if I run:

```
for /f "usebackq" %i in (`wmic process where "executablepath like '%%notepad.exe'" get ProcessId /value^|findstr ProcessId`) do @echo OUTPUT: %i
```

It gives the expected output, which in this case is:

> OUTPUT: ProcessId=2084

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found how can it be done. Due to the command was working only directly in the command prompt I decided to use `cmd /c "..."`, it's as follows:

```
for /f "usebackq delims==; tokens=1,2" %i in (`cmd /c "wmic process call create 'notepad.exe a.txt','d:\'"^|findstr ProcessId`) do @echo pid = %j
```

Now the only thing is that the `PID` needs to be trimed out of spaces, but that something else. Sorry for the inconvinience.

Comment: The key of this approach is the fact that the `,` lies in between a pair of `""`, so it is passed over to the new `cmd` instance initiated by `for /F` literally, so this works; in your original code, the `,` needed to be escaped like `^,`, that's it...

Comment: Great answer! Is there a way to minimize the window `wmic process call create '...'` creates? It'd be great if it was possible...

Comment: Thanks @Igor, this was a long while ago, I don't even remember why I was doing this . Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to initiate another `cmd` instance. You could do it as follows:

```cmd
for /F "tokens=2 delims==; " %I in ('wmic Process call create "notepad.exe a.txt"^,"D:\" ^| find "ProcessId"') do @echo PID = %I
```

You need to escape the `,` like `^,`, so the `cmd` instance initiated by the `for /F` loop receives it literally; otherwise, it becomes most likely replaced by a <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, because to `cmd` a comma is nothing but a token separator just like the <kbd>SPACE</kbd>.

---

When the given text file `a.txt` does not exist, the above code does not open a `notepad.exe` instance, even if executed without surrounding `for /F` loop:

```cmd
rem // This fails in case `a.txt` is not found, `notepad.exe` is not opened:
wmic Process call create "notepad.exe a.txt","D:\" | find "ProcessId"

rem /* When removing the pipe, `notepad.exe` is opened and a window appears:
rem    `Cannot find the a.txt file. Do you want to create a new file?`: */
wmic Process call create "notepad.exe a.txt","D:\"
```

I guess this behaviour comes from the pipe (`|`), because it initiates new `cmd` instances for either side; I believe `notepad.exe` (or any other application) is run in a kind of hidden mode where no user interaction is required (for the application not to await input in the background to no avail).

Therefore I recommend to use a variant without need of a pipe, like this:

```cmd
for /F "tokens=*" %I in ('wmic Process call create "notepad.exe a.txt"^,"D:\"') do @for /F "tokens=1-2 delims==; " %J in ("%I") do @if "%J"=="ProcessId" echo PID = %K
```

The outer `for /F` loop uses the default delimiters <kbd>TAB</kbd> and <kbd>SPACE</kbd> in order to remove the leading <kbd>TAB</kbd> in front of the keyword `ProcessId`, the inner loop contains an `if` condition to extract the correct line (instead of `find`) and splits off everything but the process ID number.