# Find out process ID of nunit of particular instance

Tags: batch-file, nunit, taskkill

I have three batch files, each opening one instance of `NUnit`. I want to kill a particular instance of `NUnit` when the tests are completed. I am able to fetch the three process ID's for three `NUnit` instances.

But is there a way to find out which processId corresponds to which Nunit instance?

Check the image below.

[image]

Here it is showing me process ID. But cannot recognize which one is for which instance.

Here is my code in batch for killing the `NUnit` process ID.

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,*" %%a in ('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq nunit.exe"') do (
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set PID=%%b
echo PID StartRun_XXX=!PID!)

::echo before loop 
:: Check for TestResult.xml file generation. 
:: at the moment when TestResult.xml generated, kill the NUNIT instance and subsequently call OverViewGenerator.bat to generate TestResult.htm


pause
:loop
if exist %~dp0TestResult_%TestCategory%_%TimeStamp%.xml (
    cd %~dp0
    echo ====================inside if exist------dp0=%~dp0===================
    pause
    echo PID=!PID!
    taskkill /PID !PID! /T
```

This code abruptly kills any nunit instance.

Comment: The for loop will overwrite the PID with all found nunit PIDs, so only the last one persists. In the if code block taskkill will only kill this last one PID.

Comment: Why not check the PID's before and after each instance? _then you can determine which PID belongs to which respective instance before deciding which to kill_.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably distinguishing `nunit` processes when they are launched.

It is possible to obtain PID of a process started through WMIC:

```
set "tab="  <<<<<<<<<<<< PLEASE insert TAB after '=' 
set "pid="
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=;=%tab% " %%i in (           
     `wmic process call create "nunit.exe"^, "C:\working\dir"`
) do if %%j gtr 0 set pid=%%j
```

(copied from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31769127/8522013%5C) answer)

Then you can save PID into a file

```
echo set "PID=%pid%" >yourfile.bat
```

To kill the process just run the script to obtain the variable

```
call yourfile.bat
taskkill /pid %pid%
taskkill /f /pid %pid%
del /y yourfile.bat
```

---

See also: [How to get the output of "wmic process call create"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43192852/how-to-get-the-output-of-wmic-process-call-create)